# triggering events called on text field change with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some javascript code that prefills an address field on homedepot.  My code works and is adding the address values to the fields, however, homedepot is doesn't accept the address until I actually detects that each field has been entered.  Setting the `.val()` for each field does not seem to be enough.  If I go in after setting the `.val()` for each and manually type at least 1 character it will work and accept the address.  How can I trigger whatever change event needs to happen so that I don't have to do this manually?

I tried using the change trigger as shown here, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#lastName').val('Doe').trigger('change');
```

All of the actual html form code is on homedepot.com checkout page.  I'm just typing the above command for each of the address fields (lastName, firstName, zip, etc) into the developer console in chrome.

Comment: Did you try triggering `keyup` or `keydown` or `keypress`? Just an idea, there's not enough code here to figure out the problem

Comment: Did you have `change` event handler attached  with `lastName` element? Note: `.trigger('change')` will only trigger event handler.

Comment: Can you post your minimum required `html` code?

Comment: I think you should provide some code so that we get some idea

Comment: are you looking for `$('#lastName').val('Doe').click()`

Comment: I'm simply typing that into the developer console, along with similar lines to fill in the rest of the form fields.    The actual form is at https://secure2.homedepot.com/mycheckout/checkout  and i'm trying to modify the address when I have 2 items in my card shipping to 2 different locations

Answer (score 0):

You need just call `change` method

```
$('#lastName').val('Doe').change();
```

Give it a try...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that and it still doesn't seem to work.  I'm typing these commands into the developer console in chrome when at the check out page at home depot.  https://secure2.homedepot.com/mycheckout/checkout  I'm trying to fill the address it and have it accept the address when I have 2 items in cart that are shipping to two different addresses.